# return xml from document with highest integer in one element

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have a rather long XML document with subsections under elements called `<Pages>`. Each of these pages contains an element called `<NumberOfEntries>` with an integer value.

I am trying to show the part of the XML from the `<Page>` which has the highest number of entries.

I have looked at the `fn:max` function, but it's not working for me ...

This is what I have tried -

```
for $x in /Document
where $x fn:max(//NumberOfEntries)
return $x//Page::node()
```

EDIT

I just worked out this one but it's returning all the pages - not just the one with the highest number of entries - any suggestions?

```
for $x in /Document
where max($x//NumberOfEntries)
return ($x//Page)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `max(...)` doesn't return boolean results, `where max($x//NumberOfEntries)` is equivalent to `where exists(max($x//NumberOfEntries))`, so it isn't filtering anything. You want to find the page that has the maximum number of entries, so here's what I'd do:

```
let $pages := /Document//Page,
    $max   := max($pages//NumberOfEntries)
return $pages[.//NumberOfEntries = $max]
```

If more than one page has the same number of entries and that's the maximum, they're all returned. If you just want one result, you can wrap the last line into `(...)[1]` to take the first one:

```
let $pages := /Document//Page,
    $max   := max($pages//NumberOfEntries)
return ($pages[.//NumberOfEntries = $max])[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
let $max := max(//Page//NumberOfEntries)
for $x in //Page
where number($x//NumberOfEntries) eq $max
return $x
```

Comment: that's also returning all the pages in the document, not just the one with the maximum number of entries. thanks though.

Comment: I'm beginning to think there's something up with XML Exchanger - that's still bringing back all the entries. I'm having the same problem with another xquery i'm running, that's bringing back all entries also.

Comment: @staceym No, my bad, got myself distracted with the count. Fixed it, though Leo's answer works too..

Comment: That is the assignment operator. The expression to its right is assigned to the variable name to its left. The 'let' is to make clear such an assignment will follow. The 'for' is not part of the expression, so just the max is assigned to $max..

Answer (score 1):

**This can be done even with a single XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
for $m in max(//Page//NumberOfEntries/xs:integer(.))
  return (//Page[(.//NumberOfEntries)[1]/xs:integer(.) eq $m])[1]
```

This selects the first (in document order) `Page` element in the XML document, that has a `NumberOfEntries` descendant whose value is the maximum observed for any such `NumberOfEntries` descendant of any `Page`.

**If you want to select** *all* **the pages with maximum number of entries, just simplify the above to**:

```
for $m in max(//Page//NumberOfEntries/xs:integer(.))
      return //Page[(.//NumberOfEntries)[1]/xs:integer(.) eq $m]
```